# How to create my own style.css file in an wordpress child-theme

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-style, css, wp-register-style

I am working in the theme called Understrap. I work in the child-theme. The theme

allready has a style.css and functions.php. I want to create my own style.css file

and overwrite that style.css they have included. Any suggestions?

Thank you very much

Comment: you can simply replace it if you don't want to use the one given at all. back it up just in case you want to revert. if you want to use an additional style sheet. create a css file with any name and enqueue it https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Comment: The template allready has an functions.php file, should i use that one or create my own functions.php?

Comment: you are asking about a specific theme that no one here is likely to know anything about. In addition there is no code that you have tried, so people can't do more than guessing. It is not clear at all what is the actual question here, is it about how to do such thing in general, best practice, or how to do it in the specific theme. That is why the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the official docs:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Make sure you are within your child theme `functions.php` and use this code to make sure the function is firing. It will kill the page if it is working correctly.

```
  function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
          wp_die('Yep! This is working');
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

Comment: hey i tried this, but still doesen't work.
 ` function add_theme_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
 
  wp_enqueue_style( 'ownstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/owncss/ownstyle.css', array(), '0.2.0', 'all');
 
  wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
 
    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );  `

Comment: @MustafaDennisUslu Updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

You need to add following code to your child-theme's functions.php

```
    /**
     * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
     */
    function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-css', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/css/custom.css', array(), '1.0.0' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

Comment: hmm it doesent work, i might be doing something wrong: 
```
```